# How to use limit_conn and limit_req modules of Nginx when it is behind HAProxy

Tags: nginx, haproxy, rate-limiting

I'm using `limit_conn_zone` (with `limit_conn`) and `limit_req_zone` (with `limit_req`) in `Nginx` which sits behind a `HAProxy`. They both run on the same host.

I see whenever a limit is breached in `Nginx` (resulting in 503 responses), the client IP is `127.0.0.1`. This is probably because the only connected client is in fact HAProxy.

This makes me wonder whether the usage of `limit_conn` and `limit_req` module behind `HAProxy` is effective, as it seems to me that `Nginx` is effectively limiting requests from `HAProxy` but not those from actual users. If this is true, how should I adapt these settings for my set-up?

Comment: i belive you looking for like `https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2019/06/04/real-client-ip-address-nginx-behind-haproxy-reverse-proxy/&ved=2ahUKEwjBlvu57dXoAhVvMOwKHWDGAIYQFjACegQIChAM&usg=AOvVaw2ozL5Jw2MvV9jpTHVdNNOi`

Answer (score 0):

I'd give a try to [RealIP](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) module, but that's just a theory.

**UPD.**: See this "[nginx behind load balancer](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3052266)" thread